# Make changes to database only if all queries execute successfully

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sometimes I have to delete two records on different tables. How could I execute the query in a way where if one fails the other one will not execute and the other way around. In other words, that the database gets updated only if both queries are successful otherwise don't make any changes. That way if I get any errors I know nothing has changed. I am executing this query in C# as:

```
//qDelete is a string containing the query
// connection - SqlConnection 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qDelete, connection);
try
{
    var t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Query succesfully executed \n \n" + "\n\n" + t + " records successfully deleted");
}
catch
{
    //do something here to avoid having any changes to the database          
}
```

That's is great. My sDelete string gets build dynamically and the only things that I am missing is to place the statements in the right order. I have figured that I have to delete first the records from the dependent table or table that has constrains then from the other table. How could I see which table is dependent on the other will help me build this query. I could do something like sort all the strings and place the ones that contains the table that has no constrain first then place the other ones. How can I find out which table depends on the other to make this even better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) to gather the two updates together and let them either both succeed or neither happen. That link includes a sample that does two inserts, but you can easily adapt it for two deletes.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use a Transaction. Using the SqlConnection, begin a Transaction using the BeginTransaction() method; it will return a SqlTransaction. Then, there is an overload of the SqlCommand constructor that will take the transaction as well as the connection. Run the command(s), and at the end of the try block, call the Commit() method on the transaction. If you catch an error, call Rollback() on the transaction.

Comment: do you know what versions transactions work on? Is it only 2008 or do previous versions support this?

Comment: Transactions are kind of a big deal in DB data maintenance, so I would expect you to have access to them in any framework that gives you ADO.NET. Certainly the .NET Framework 2.0 and on (which is VS2005) will have transactional support.

Comment: I mean versions of SQL Server, is transaction based on the framework, or is based on the database? (Does the database to support it).

Comment: SQL Server 2000 and later, for sure, will give you transactional support. I'm also pretty sure it goes back further than that; like I said, ACID transactions are a cornerstone of RDBMSes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the transaction support of ADO.Net. Try

```
    private static void DemoFunc() 
       {
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");//conection string here
          SqlTransaction transaction;
          SqlCommand cmd;

          conn.Open();
          transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
          try 
          {
             cmd = new SqlCommand("Your Query1", conn, transaction);//Your query in place of Your Query1 
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             cmd = new SqlCommand("Your Query2", conn, transaction);//Your query in place of Your Query2         
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             transaction.Commit();
          } 
          catch (SqlException sqlError) 
          {
             transaction.Rollback();
          }
          conn.Close();
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on SQLCommand Transactions.

http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/07/working-with-ado-net-transactions/